# How to pass different CSV value for every occurance in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am trying to pass different CSV Value in sequential manner for every occurrence in Jmeter.
I applied

- Loop count

  Counter

  Beanshell Sampler

  Value from CSV
- JMS Point to Point Request

With this i am able to pass different value for every occurrence for multiple users.
But my script fails when i run for multi user multiple iterations.
It is not picking up sequential value.
My beanshell sampler code-

```
String variablename=vars.get("variable");
String csvvalue=vars.get("valuefromcsv");
vars.put(variablename,csvvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me that you need to use scripting at all, it's quite sufficient to set up [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and:

1. Point it to CSV file
2. Set up ["Sharing Mode"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) to be `All Threads`

This way each thread (virtual user) will be picking up the next value from the CSV file on each iteration.

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the script for this. you can "Config Element-> CSV data set config" for the HTTP request. under CSV data set config page set the below values.
Variable names: give column names.
Delimiter : should be ,
Recycle of EOF: True
stop thread on EOF : false
Sharing mode : All threads.